# Filter minute data in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column with the minutes ("MINUTOS") of each player's game, and it is of type "object".
I need to filter the data only with the players who have played more than 15 minutes.
I tried .loc and other options but I have not succeeded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following:

```py
df_filtered = df[df['MINUTOS'].str.split(':').str[0].map(int)>=15]
```